# Xilinx ISE: Should I be concerned about warning Xst:653?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx-ise

I never mention anything related to `GND_3_o` or `PWR_3_o` in my code. What are these signals, should I be concerned about these warnings related to them, and if so, how can I fix them?

```
WARNING:Xst:653 - Signal <GND_3_o> is used but never assigned. This sourceless signal will be automatically connected to value GND.
WARNING:Xst:653 - Signal <PWR_3_o> is used but never assigned. This sourceless signal will be automatically connected to value GND.
```

Comment: Find out where they are used ... there will be a message "analyzing unit xxx" or some such just before them. If it's a Xilinx IP core, and you're confident you're using it OK, ignore them. Though `PWR_3_0` sounds like something that ought to be '1' rather than `0`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XST Warning 653 is a critical warning and should be fixed in your design, otherwise some features won't work as expected.

> WARNING:Xst:653 - Signal  is used but never assigned. This sourceless signal will be automatically connected to value GND.

GND_3_o sounds like an auto generated signal. Elements in vectors ofter get translated to signal names with underscores.